# Laravel Redirect back to same page after changing locale

Tags: laravel, redirect, localization, locale, multilingual

The way I implemented multilang is through middleware and routes.

Middleware Localization.php looks like this:

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
    $locale = $request->segment(1); 


    if(empty($locale)) { 
        return redirect()->to('/' . app()->getLocale());
    }

    if(in_array($locale, ['en','it'])) {
        App::setLocale($locale);
        $request->except(0); 
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

And in my web.php I have:

```
Route::get('locale/{locale}', function ($locale){

  \Session::put('locale', $locale);
  $path = Route::getCurrentRoute()->getPath();

  return redirect($path);

})->name('langroute');
```

In blade I'm using it like this:

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ url('/en') }}">
```

How can I redirect back to same page after changing to another lang?

Comment: Ok, if it didn't work for you, take a look at this controller, it's working. https://github.com/akaunting/language/blob/master/src/Controllers/Language.php

Comment: That is a package and the implementation is completely different form mine so I cannot solve my issue with his controller method... As I specified I used only middleware and routes for implementing multilang...

Comment: It gets the previous url from two sources, one from globals and one from cookie, you can also use both ways to get the previous url.

Comment: The way I'm redirecting is through `href`. I've tried with `{{route(Route::currentRouteName(), 'en') }}` but it will give me error with parameters on pages routes that are requiring parameters.

Comment: there's a `->withInput()` flag which includes the previous querystring. Maybe it can help.

Comment: Yeah but this is not the case I think

Comment: Anyway thank you bro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sharing a global variable to all of your views as following in your `AppServiceProvider`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
/**
 * Register any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function register()
{
    //
}

/**
 * Bootstrap any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    $thisUrl = url()->current().'/';
    if (app()->getlocale() == 'en') {
        $newUrl  = str_replace('/en/', '/it/', $thisUrl);
    }else{
        $newUrl  = str_replace('/it/', '/en/', $thisUrl);
    }
    View::share('newUrl', $newUrl);
}
}
```

And you can redirect in blade same like before:

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ $newUrl }}">
```